# Salesforce Flow: Error Handling

Tags: visual-workflow, error-messages

I have a screen flow and i want to manage Error Handling. So, in the "Fault" path, i have added a screen element where i show the {!$Flow.FaultMessage}. The problem is, that the FaultMessage shows a text that is not that much User-Friendly. Highlighted is the message that i want to Show. I couldn't find a "safe" way where with formulas i could get the required sub-string.

Any ideas on how i could "omit" the rest of the String?

[image]

Comment: It is annoying, isn't it?! It rather depends on exactly what the flow element was that had the fault (did you use standard record update?), but it is possible to have apex code return clean messages from validation failures to give a good UX in this sort of scenario (using invokable methods). I'd be interested to see if someone has a more OOTB means to deal with this.

Comment: May also be worth looking in unofficialsf.com to see if there are some goodies available that fit the bill...?

Comment: Hi Phil, true, it's a bit annoying. I use Standard Record Update. Seems too much to call an invocable APEX just because the Error Handling is not that "beautiful". I will check unofficialsf.com in order to examine whether somehow they cover the requirement. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Formula resource

- Name: **getLabelFromError**
- Type : Text
- Formula :

```
   IF(CONTAINS({!$Flow.FaultMessage},"Your custom Error"),
   "Your custom Error", 
   "An unmanaged error occurred. Please contact your Administrator and try again")
```

---

Add Screen element

- Display Text

  - {!**getLabelFromError**}

Comment: Good answer, upvoted. Welcome to SFSE!

Answer (score 1):

You can try below formula to extract your fault message for the scenario of validation rule exception.

MID(text, start_num, num_chars)
FIND(search_text, text ,[start_num])
LEN(text)

Formula based on the above syntax mentioned -

MID({!$Flow.FaultMessage}, FIND('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION: ', {!$Flow.FaultMessage}) + LEN('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION: '),  FIND('. You can look up ExceptionCode', {!$Flow.FaultMessage}) - FIND('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION: ', {!$Flow.FaultMessage}) - LEN('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION: '))